# Reordering the XML based on a node value

Tags: xml, sorting

I have a XML that need to be sorted on the base of student ID, Please suggest efficient way to do it.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <StudentData xmlns="http://www.example.org/consolidated">
 <Student>
 <StudentID>1</StudentID>
 <StudentBranch>CSE</StudentBranch>
 </Student>
 <Student>
 <StudentID>5</StudentID>
 <StudentBranch>ECE</StudentBranch>
 </Student>
 <Student>
<StudentID>3</StudentID>
<StudentBranch>MECH</StudentBranch>
 </Student>
 <Student>
<StudentID>7</StudentID>
<StudentBranch>MECH</StudentBranch>
</Student>
</StudentData>
```

Comment: have you already tried something?

Comment: I tried  Java code, But has a doubt that existing Transformation technoligies like XSLT would be help. So i am seeking for a efficient way for the implemetation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the xsl:sort function inside an xsl:for-each, which should be quiet efficient. So something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="StudentData/Student">
      <xsl:sort select="StudentID"/>
      <!-- your code here, e.g. create new Student Element-->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```